# Conversion from string "valor" to type 'Integer' is not valid in VB.NET

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net

I'm a C# programmer but now I have to code VB.NET and I having a situation trying to translate this line of C# code to VB.NET

what I want is to check if the value that I obtained via MySQLDataReader is DBNull, in C# I use this to check if a string value is null or not

```
data.empName = dr.IsDBNull(1) ? "No name !!!" : dr.GetString(1).ToString();
```

But now I need the same verification but in VB.NET and also the data type retrieved via MySQLDataReader is decimal, this is what I got for the time beign

```
IIf(dr.IsDBNull("valor"), 0.0, dr.GetDecimal(dr.GetOrdinal("valor")))
```

but when I debug the app got the error message:

An exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Conversion from string "valor" to type 'Integer' is not valid.

the data type in the MySQL table is Decimal(10,2), could you please help me and tell me what am I doing wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line should have read, the evaluation of `dr.IsDBNull("valor")` was incorrect and caused the exception. To remedy, try this

```
IIf(dr.IsDBNull(dr.GetOrdinal("valor")), 0.0, dr.GetDecimal(dr.GetOrdinal("valor")))
```